# Onde ficam armazenadas as instruções de um processador?

Tags: assembly, arquitetura-computadores

Estou estudando arquitetura de computadores, e estou muito confuso em relação ao conjunto de instruções de um processador. Quando escrevemos algo, por exemplo, `ADD A1, B1`, o processador soma o valor do registrador A1 com B1 e armazena o resultado em A1. Porém, como e aonde ficam armazenadas essas informações de instruções? As instruções ficam armazenadas no próprio processador e são inseridas no momento da fabricação? Por exemplo, um processador com arquitetura CISC será sempre CISC ou é possível "reprogramar" para que seja RISC?

Answer (score 6):

> Porém, como e aonde ficam armazenadas essas informações de instruções? As instruções ficam armazenadas no próprio processador e são inseridas no momento da fabricação?

As instruções são armazenadas na memória, e buscadas por meio de registradores específicos que normalmente levam nomes tais como *data pointer*, *stack pointer*, *instruction pointer*, entre outros. Nestes registradores são armazenados valores que correspondem a endereços de memória de onde as instruções são buscadas, e a execução dessas mesmas instruções atualizam os seus valores de forma que passem a apontar para a próxima instrução a ser executada. Dessa forma, o processador utiliza esses registradores para buscar na memória a próxima instrução a ser executada.

O acesso a memória principal é lento, mas como essas instruções serão acessadas múltiplas vezes em sequência, então devido ao princípio da localidade temporal e espacial das instruções e da memória, na maioria das vezes estas instruções serão localizadas na cache L1.

Supondo que o registrador que aponte para a próxima instrução seja chamado de *instruction pointer*, então o processo de atualizar o valor desses registradores pode consistir em:

- Apenas incrementar o valor do *instruction pointer* para pegar a instrução subsequente ou;
- Alterar-se o valor do *instruction pointer* para algum outro bem diferente no caso de desvios condicionais ou incondicionais ou;
- No caso de chamada de rotinas, armazenar a instrução subsequente ao retorno na memória, em uma posição definida por um registrador que contenha o endereço de uma pilha para isso (*stack pointer*), armazenar o endereço da primeira instrução da rotina invocada no *instruction pointer*, e quando a subrotina finalizar, por meio do *stack pointer*, o valor da instrução subsequente é atribuído ao *instruction pointer*.

> Por exemplo, um processador com arquitetura CISC será sempre CISC ou é possível "reprogramar" para que seja RISC?

Não, ele não pode ser reprogramado. A arquitetura RISC ou CISC corresponde ao projeto interno do processador físico, estando diretamente relacionado com o número e a organização dos nanocomponentes eletrônicos (composto quase exclusivamente de portas lógicas e flip-flops que por sua vez são compostas de transistores) que o compõem.

A principal diferença entre o RISC e o CISC é o número e a complexidade das instruções que eles são capazes de interpretar. O CISC segue a ideia de que o processador deve ser capaz de decodificar um grande número de diferentes instruções, talvez em diversos formatos, de forma a tornar-se poderoso e sofisticado. Já o RISC segue a ideia que o conjunto de instruções deve ser mínimo e todas elas terem o mesmo ou quase o mesmo formato, tornando-se então muito mais simples.

Existe também uma arquitetura híbrida RISC e CISC que embora seja um processador de instruções CISC, internamente ele corresponde a um processador RISC interpretando um conjunto fixo de instruções CISC, aonde cada instrução CISC é traduzida em uma sequência de instruções RISC. A tal conjunto de instruções que faz a tradução do CISC para o RISC se dá o nome de microcódigo.

Já o microcódigo é o único código que está sim escrito dentro do processador híbrido RISC/CISC como parte de seu circuito eletrônico na forma de uma série de flip-flops. Uma vez que o microcódigo está escrito como parte do microcircuito eletrônico do processador, ele não pode ser alterado.

Comment: O que seria os *flip-flops*?

Comment: @gato https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop